# why is Hover effect opacity not working after build

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I Have a simple hover effect on a button that is nested in a link.
Here is the button :

```js
 <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`} >
      <button  className='btn-4'>View </button>
 </Link>
```

and here is the css for it :

```js
.btn-4 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  border: none;
  background-color: var(--drk-black);
  color: var(--light-grey-2);
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-4:hover {
  opacity: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

It works normally on localhost  but the opacity is not changing after building  however the cursor is becoming a pointer.
Can somebody explain to me why this is happening please?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this thanks to this answer :
[opacity percentage changed to 1%](https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/issues/118)
so I ended up changing the opacity from 50% to 0.5.